# jade.compileClient fails when invoking jade.escape

Tags: javascript, pug

I am using `jade.compileClient` to convert jade files to JS functions and I am having an issue when using escaped html.

When in jade I write:

```
h2= conditional ? 'String1 ' + moreText : otherCondition ? 'String2' : 'String3'
```

It is converted to:

```
function template(locals) {
var buf = [];
var jade_mixins = {};
var jade_interp;
buf.push("<h2>" + (jade.escape(null == (jade_interp = conditional ? 'String1 ' + moreText : otherCondition ? 'String2' : 'String3') ? "" : jade_interp)) + "</h2>"); 

// [more code, beside the point]
```

Seems great! The only problem is that the `jade` object doesnt exists (at least in my code), and, as you see, the converted functions calls to `jade.escape` (and some other functions like `jade.attr`, in other cases).

How can I make it work? Is something that I have to include that I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using `jade/runtime`:

```
var jade = require('jade/runtime');    
var html = fs.readFileSync(filename);
var fn = jade.compileClient(html, { filename: filename });

fn(locals);
```

You can also download it from [this link](https://github.com/jadejs/jade/blob/master/runtime.js).

Comment: I had this same issue and the solution was to add the require.js to the client side code (in my case using bower). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814153/jade-escape-is-undefined-on-compiled-jade-template#comment50486349_16376622